# SVG animation is not working in Edge or IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have a checkmark SVG animation that works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc but does not work in Edge and IE (surprise surprise).

It seems as if the SVG is there but the strokes are not displaying.

As far as I can tell both Edge and IE11 support what I am trying to do and I've used every prefix I can think of.

CSS/HTML:

```css
.checkmark {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 22px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline;
    stroke-width: 6;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    margin: -4px -15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #fff;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
            animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 166;
    stroke-dashoffset: 166;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-animation: stroke .6s cubic-bezier(0.650, 0.000, 0.450, 1.000) forwards;
            animation: stroke .6s cubic-bezier(0.650, 0.000, 0.450, 1.000) forwards;
}

.checkmark__check {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke-dasharray: 48;
    stroke-dashoffset: 48;
    -webkit-animation: stroke .3s cubic-bezier(0.650, 0.000, 0.450, 1.000) .8s forwards;
            animation: stroke .3s cubic-bezier(0.650, 0.000, 0.450, 1.000) .8s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: none;
                transform: none;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
                transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes scale {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: none;
                transform: none;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
                transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
    100% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #B0D056;
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #B0D056;
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    100% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #B0D056;
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #B0D056;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 52 52">
     <circle class="checkmark__circle"
             cx="26"
             cy="26"
             r="25"
             fill="none"/>
     <path class="checkmark__check"
           fill="none"
           d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>
```

Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I used caniuse and saw somewhere else on here that a recent Edge patch included support for this. Honestly I just threw IE on here to see if someone had an easy fix for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after some research I found that in Edge, you have to be more specific when dealing with stroke-dashoffset and stroke-dasharray so instead of '0' you have to put '0px';

```
@keyframes stroke {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;  /* instead of stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
    }
}
```

IE does not support CSS animations of SVGs and never will

Comment: I have the same issue, if you have got any answer please comment.